# Switching Element Location Via JQUERY

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I wanted to achieve an effect to switch the position of the 2 HTML Divisions when they are clicked.

So when clicked, the top will shift to the bottom and bottom will shift to the top.

Here is what I can come up with

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('div').click(
            function(){
                $(this).insertBefore($(this).next());
            }
        );
        }
        )
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
  body{
    margin: 0;
   }
    #top{
height: 100px; 
width: 100px;
background: rgb(206,206,203);
    }

    #bottom{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px; 
background: rgb(226,206,203);
     }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there is a way to select the specific Element using class in the Jquery selector as follows

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('div').click(
            function(){
                **$('#bottom').insertBefore('#top');**
            }
        );
        }
        )
  </script>
```

But I just wanted an generic way to shift elements with arbitrary names and class names.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a unique class to associate each pair, then you can do something like:

```
$('.pair').click( function() {
    $('.pair:first').insertAfter( $('.pair:not(:first)') );
});
```

Comment: I have another question. How can this permanently affect the layout of the Dom? Can this switch be saved permanently on the markup?

Comment: @webzide -- you'd have to send back the change to the server via AJAX and have the server-side understand how to generate the page based on some persistent knowledge of the ordering of the divs for that particular user.  That is you store the order in a database, associated with the user.   When you generate the page, you generate the divs in the user's preferred order.  In the click handler you pass back to a server action, the new order and it saves it in the database so that the next time the page is generated, it's generated in the new order.